Issue with Ubuntu 24.04: Black Screen with Cursor on Login
I am currently using Ubuntu 24.04. When I turn on my PC and log in using my password, it lands on a black screen with only the mouse cursor visible. I am unable to perform any actions, including turning off my PC.
I found that pressing Ctrl+Alt+F4 allows me to switch to a terminal where I can log in using my username and password. After logging in, I can reboot my PC using the command line, and it works fine temporarily. However, the issue persists after some time, and I have to repeat the same steps again.
I am looking for a permanent solution to this problem.
Thank you!

Anyone encountering this issue, please go here and click Does this bug affect you? under the bug title so that we can get more visibility: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/2089709

Yes, please do what bmaupin says. But note that you'll need an Ubuntu One account. Find the link on the left side just under the bug title.

In ubuntu 24.04,lts the display manager which used is 'gdm'.I changed the gdm to 'lightdm' now everything works fine for me.
To change the display manager from gdm to lightdm
 sudo apt update
 sudo apt install lightdm

During the installation, you might be prompted to choose the default display manager. If not, you can manually reconfigure it:
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm

You will be presented with a dialog to choose the default display manager. Select lightdm or gdm3 as per your preference.
Restart your system:
sudo reboot


Would one go back by using sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm?

Same problem here on several stations with Ubuntu 24.04.1
Randomly after entering the password, the screen goes black with an X, when pressing ctrl+alt+f4, I enter with the user, reboot and it works.
I found another method that has worked, pressing Windows+L, the system will lock, with that the screen will reappear, just entering the credentials again, ideally it would be a definitive solution, but it is better than rebooting :)

How is this an answer?

@DavidDE The language in this answer could be improved, but  it appears that this answer is saying that he presses Ctrl+Alt+F4 to bring up a text-only virtual console screen, enters his username and password to login, and then runs sudo reboot which works. All in all this answer looks OK to me.

Does not fix the problem the OP himself says that. Reads like he has to do this every time.

Try pressing enter and then typing your password (nothing will be shown on screen).
I ran into a similar situation and found that the login screen was being shown on another display (multi-monitor setup). In my case, this was a dummy HDMI plug to enable the video card when no monitors were present.
If that works, it was just that the login screen is on a display you can't see. I have yet to find a way to get the login screen to ignore the dummy plug in 24.04.

OP has already stated that a terminal login works.

Indeed terminal login works for me as well. However, they can better troubleshoot the issue if they confirm that the login screen may also be shown on the wrong display.

Superhard to log in on a login screen that may or may not exist.

This was it for me. I have two video cards and the one not plugged into anything somehow got switched to after the initial boot sequence

I think but not sure this is issue related to your graphic card drivers
For update or install your graphic drivers, open your terminal(Ctrl + Alt + F4) and type:
ubuntu-drivers install

and reboot
reboot

If there is still a problem
You can purge your graphic driver and install again:
sudo apt purge ~nvidia
sudo apt auto remove
sudo apt clean

and install with apt or ubuntu-drivers again
apt:
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade

ubuntu-drivers:
ubuntu-drivers install

and reboot
reboot

Refrences:
https://www.aptgetlife.co.uk/fixing-ubuntu-black-screen-with-blinking-cursor/

Still the issue persist.It shows the cursor pointer and the black screen now when i close the lid of my laptop and reopen it shows the display.what is the problem can u please suggest me the solution..!!

I have this problem and I don't even have AMD nor NVidia card.

Changing to lightdm seemed like it only worked for a very short time for me, as the problem came back within minutes. But I found a longer term solution:
Use ctrl+alt+f4 to get to a login prompt, and then edit your /etc/default/grub file e.g.
sudo vim /etc/default/grub

You want to empty out the following variable (i.e. set it to an empty string):
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""

Once done, you can save and close the file, and then run:
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot

If you are using VMWare for virtualization, another solution is to disable "Accelerate 3D graphics" under Display VM Settings.

You can try that. This works for me :
edit the file /etc/pam.d/login :
sudo nano /etc/pam.d/login

and comment this line with #, and restart :
#session optional pam_lastlog.so 


First, if you get this issue, please go here and click Does this bug affect you? under the bug title so that we can get more visibility: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/2089709
Add more details to the bug as you're able to help it get fixed.
Beyond that, as for me I only noticed this bug when I log in using X11 but I don't notice it in Wayland.
To log in using Wayland:

If you're logged in, click the icons in the far top right of the screen > click the power icon > Log Out

At the login screen, click the gear icon near the lower-right

Choose Ubuntu and log in
(The Ubuntu on Xorg option will use X11)


